Deploy laravel 11 on Hostinger
I'm trying to upload the laravel 11 project to Hostinger. I connected GIT from the Hostinger management panel (Advanced-> GIT) and the GitHub files are correctly uploaded to hostinger in the "/public_html/" folder
When I try to access the site I get the 403 error, but trying various guides I modified the htaccess file, but the error changes to 500 or always 403 based on the htaccess configuration that I found online
EDIT: I solved htaccess problem and now I can see my homepage, but can't navigate all the routes
SOLVED: added this htaccess file to the laravel public folder:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]


can you provide the .htaccess file?

answers go in answer posts. not in the question post.

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

Create a .htaccess file in the Laravel home directory and add the code I gave.
This code will redirect incoming requests to public/index.php.
Note: After installing on the server, don't forget to install the dependencies with composer.

Tried this, but now I have 404 on all routes

Have you solved it?
